# Cannot find "Foundation" type in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode6, foundation

In Xcode 6 it says language instead of type.I'm learning Objective-c from a book and it asks me to make a project under the Foundation type. The book is made for Xcode 5 but It should work with Xcode 6. Where do I find "Foundation" framework?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to File -> New Project. Select the OSX tab on the left, then select "Command Line Tool". Press Ok. This creates a project using the Foundation framework.

Answer (score -1):

Simply choose 'Objective-C' from the list of languages(that goes for 'type' in late versions of Xcode.